# Amazon Redshift C# client to query data without ODBC/JDBC

Tags: c#, sdk, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

Is there is any way to fetch the data from Amazon Redshift from C# without using JDBC/ODBC drivers?

Comment: `psql -h <host> -p <port> -U <username> -W <password> <database>`

Comment: I mean, whether we can achieve it using c#? in .NET.     Is there is any library to do it?

Comment: Something you could check, I read it in past , but I have no idea about .net. I'm java developer. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=246947

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Npgsql, I've seen customers have success using it.
 [npgsql](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/compatibility.html)

Comment: I can fetch the data using postgresql queries using npgsql. Thanks.